# Backup SQL Server using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database-backups, sqlsrv

I would like to backup the database on a SQL Server 2017 using a PHP script and put the file in my filesystem on the webserver (IIS).

My PHP script:

```
$sql = "BACKUP DATABASE BGEDB TO DISK='\\\WWWDEV02\WWWDEV02-BGEDB\backups\BGEDB.bak'";
// $sql = BACKUP DATABASE BGEDB TO DISK='\\WWWDEV02\WWWDEV02-BGEDB\backups\BGEDB.bak'
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt) {
  echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";
}
else {
  echo "Error in statement execution.\n";
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

The result:

> Error in statement execution. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 4035 [code] => 4035 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]536 Seiten wurden für die BGEDB-Datenbank, Datei "BGEDB" für Datei 2, verarbeitet. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]536 Seiten wurden für die BGEDB-Datenbank, Datei "BGEDB" für Datei 2, verarbeitet. ) )

In SQL Server Management Studio there is no problem using the command in $sql:

```
BACKUP DATABASE BGEDB TO DISK='\\WWWDEV02\WWWDEV02-BGEDB\backups\BGEDB.bak'
```

Please could anybody help me with my problem? Is it because of the user-rights between the SQL Server and the webserver? Or have I done anything wrong with escaping the backslashes in PHP?

Edit:

I've written a stored procedure called BGEDB_Backup in the SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BGEDB_Backup 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BACKUP DATABASE BGEDB TO DISK='\\WWWDEV02\WWWDEV02-BGEDB\backups\Datenbank_per_Skript\BGEDB1.bak'
END
GO
```

When I run this in Management Studio the backup-file will be written in the filesystem of the IIS-Webserver. Now I've tried to exec the stored procedure in my php:

```
$sql = "EXEC BGEDB_Backup";
echo "SQL ---> ".$sql."<br /><br />";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt) {
  echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";
}
else {
  echo "Error in statement execution.\n";
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Unfortunately nothing happens in the filesystem of the webserver...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are definetly escaping wrongly in the very first line. It should be `"BACKUP DATABASE BGEDB TO DISK='\\\\WWWDEV02\\WWWDEV02-BGEDB\\backups\\BGEDB.bak'"` assuming you need two slashes in the front.

Comment: Thanks! But $sql looks quite the same and so the result... :-(

Comment: @RalfSemroch Possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760895/php-calling-sqlserver-backup-database-script-backup-file-created-and-then-delet/48762258#48762258).

Comment: @Zhorov - thank you, I've tested switching the warning off, the PHP script is not dying anymore but the backup file will not be created in the filesystem of the webserver. Perhaps there will be a problem with the user-rights between the SQL Server and the Webserver. I've written a mail to my administration...