# PHP SQL Query not waiting for restore to finish

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter-3, sqlsrv

I'm using CI 3 and PHP SQLSRV module. I've noticed that with a restore it will try to go onto the next line before the restore is done. I'm not sure why that is happening but is there anyway for me to keep checking to see if it is done before moving on to the next line?

```
$dbserv = $this->load->database('dbserver',true);
sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 0);
$query = "
   RESTORE DATABASE $dbname FROM DISK = '$restoredir$backupselected' WITH REPLACE, 
   MOVE '$dataname' TO '$datadir$dbname$dataprepend', 
   MOVE '$logname' TO '$logdir$dbname$logprepend'
";
$restore = $dbserv->query($query);
```

Comment: What is the value of `$restore` variable after the execution of line `$restore=$dbserv->query($query);`?

Comment: A similar Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760895/php-calling-sqlserver-backup-database-script-backup-file-created-and-then-delet/48762258#48762258) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64018598/backup-sql-server-database-using-php/64041766#64041766).

Comment: @Zhorov object(CI_DB_sqlsrv_result)#34 (9) { ["scrollable"]=> string(8) "buffered" ["conn_id"]=> resource(80) of type (SQL Server Connection) ["result_id"]=> resource(82) of type (SQL Server Statement) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> NULL ["row_data"]=> NULL }